# In mvc how can i achieve loading animation while page is transforming from one to another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried some code for to get loading symbol while page is moving from one to another.
How can i get it when i clicked on submit button on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best Async jQuery progress indicator for long running tasks.You can use this for page navigation and inserting data to database http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-01-02/asp_net-mvc_3-async-jquery-progress-indicator-long-running-tasks

Comment: Here is the link for multiple progress bars.Just use plugin what ever you want.keep in mind to accept answer if it is help.http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/progress%20bar/

Comment: dude u have any example regarding this?. plz help me